# ring of integers in a cubic extension of a cyclotomic function field

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ where $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ and let $R$ be the polynomial ring $K[x]$. Let $L$ be the field $K(x)[y]$ where $y$ satisfies $y^3=1+x^2$.

Which is the integral closure of $R$ in $L$, why?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  Would you know how to find the integral closure of ${\mathbf Z}$ in ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$? In ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$?

Comment: @KCd no, this is a 2011 written exam in number theory, i've no homeworks to do. no, i don't know integral closure you said

Comment: @KCd i suppose $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$

Comment: Since it is an old number theory exam problem, I think understanding the examples of integral closures in those cubic number fields should come before the case of function fields. That is, if you can't find the algebraic integers in a pure cubic field like ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ then I think that is something to focus on before working out ${\mathbf Q}(\omega)(x,\sqrt[3]{1+x^2})$. The analogy is that $T^3 - 2$ in ${\mathbf Z}[T]$ is similar to $T^3 - (1+x^2)$ in ${\mathbf Q}(\omega)[x][T]$: each is Eisenstein at a certain prime.

Comment: Does "i suppose ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$" mean you *can* do that case?  If so, think carefully about the analogy I mentioned in my previous comment. Instead, if you're just guessing that ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is the answer for ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ (it is the answer), then you should learn how to prove the answer for that example and then transfer the ideas to the function field case.

Comment: @KCd thank you for your suggestion, now i work on it! (yes, it was only a guess :)) )